# How to rewrite a script using metaprogramming in DolphinDB?

Tags: metaprogramming, dolphindb

```
st = take(`a, 7) join take(`b, 6)
date = 2023.08.01 + 0 1 3 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 8 9
val = 35 34 35.79 33.26 32.88 33.73 31 25 24 22 25.79 21 31
t = table(st, date, val)
marketDay = 2023.08.01 + 0 1 2 3 6 7 8 9
re = select last(val) from t group by st, interval(date, 1d, 0) as date
```

I want to generate `select last(val) from t group by st, interval(date, 1d, 0) as date` using metaprogramming. However, the second grouping condition, `interval(date, 1d, 0)`, is not a unary function so the `sqlCol` function cannot be used to generate metaexpressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `makeUnifiedCall` or `makeCall` to generate metacode for function call as follows:

```
makeUnifiedCall(funcByName(interval), [sqlCol(date), parseExpr(`1d), 0])


sql(select=sqlCol("val",last), from=t, groupBy=[<st>,<interval(date, 1d, 0) as date >], groupFlag=1).eval()
```

The following is the result:

```
st  date    last_val
a   2023.08.01  35
a   2023.08.02  34
a   2023.08.03  0
a   2023.08.04  35.79
a   2023.08.05  0
a   2023.08.06  0
a   2023.08.07  33.26
a   2023.08.08  32.88
a   2023.08.09  33.73
a   2023.08.10  31
b   2023.08.01  25
b   2023.08.02  24
b   2023.08.03  22
b   2023.08.04  25.79
b   2023.08.05  0
b   2023.08.06  0
b   2023.08.07  0
b   2023.08.08  0
b   2023.08.09  21
b   2023.08.10  31
```